# mount shared folder in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, mount

I am emulating elementary OS via VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro.

In Terminal this command as root

```
mount -t vboxsf source destination
```

outputs:

```
mount: unknown file system type ‘vboxsf‘
```

Guest additions were installed.

Comment: Does something https://askubuntu.com/questions/456400/why-cant-i-access-a-shared-folder-from-within-my-virtualbox-machine here help?

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for, but I would like to make you aware of VMware Player.

I used to use Virtualbox then found VMware Player two weeks ago. I find it to be far more smooth and a higher quality than Virtualbox. 

If you continue to have issue with Virtualbox, give VMware Player a try.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `vboxfs`? Try it instead ;)

Comment: I really think it is `vboxsf` indeed

Comment: I'm using `vboxfs` on my Mac but I have a weird installation setup for VirtualBox so it might be different from @MarcVB.

The [Ubuntu VirtualBox help for Shared Folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) Troubleshooting section suggests the same *rename to vboxfs* thing. Let's just wait for his feedback and hope this works for him.